# Trigger bottle function without reloading page

Tags: python, html, bottle

my bottle app.py looks something like:

```
@route('/submit/<var>')
def submit(var):
  # do action
  redirect("/")
```

and i have a simple html button which redirects to the required page when clicked through

`onclick="window.location.href='/submit/value'"`

but this causes the whole page to effectively refresh by going to the link and then coming back straight away, putting the user to the top of the page and so on.

How can i get it to do the bottle backend without refreshing?

Comment: You probably want to look into AJAX

Comment: How would i achieve this through AJAX?

Comment: Because it's not the sole job of the framework to handle page loading (I.e. it would be exactly the same idea if you were using Flask). It needs only to give a response. You need some JQuery code to dictate what part of the page is refreshed. Explaining AJAX  is too broad here but it's easily searchable. The idea being that your bottle code only returns a subset of the page and AJAX only updates, say, a custom `<div>`

Comment: thanks for the advice, i will look into that. do you want to give an example of this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your template:

```
<button type="button" onclick="onSubmit('Value')">Sumbit!</button>>
<p id="response"></p>
<script>
function onSubmit(value) {
    var myRequest = new Request('/submit/' + value);
    var myInit = { method: 'PUT' };
    fetch(myRequest, myInit).then(function(response) {
        return $("#response").text(response);
    });
}
</script>
```

In the python side

```
@put("/submit/<val>")
def submit(val):
    return "Yay it worked!"
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but i am receiving 'PUT 405, method not allowed', any ideas?

Comment: did you use @route/get instead of @put ? (see my example...)

Comment: sorry, I didn't see that initially. However, i still receive the 405 error :(

Comment: That fixed it! Sorry, i didn't initially see that and made changes to the template trying to debug that i forgot about. Thank you very much kind sir